# Internet Explorer 10 canvas clipping unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, clipping

In an html5 canvas application I use clipping to redraw damaged parts of the canvas like so:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(30, 30, 100, 100);
ctx.rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
ctx.clip();
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
```

I also created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22NYb/) which illustrates the problem. On every capable browser except IE10 it will display two black overlapping rectangles.

Now the question is whether this is a IE10 bug or because it adheres to the standards more closely it is actually expected behavior and just luck that it works in every other browser. If so, what would be the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

one possible circumvention of this obvious IE10 bug is to clear the rectangles one by one. one advantage: its faster as it doesn't require setting a clip

Comment: this is actually true. thanks for this. it still does not work once you have an irrectangular clip such as a triangle so this issue remains an annoying bug!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call ctx.fill(); at the end

Comment: No, I want to clear this part to repaint it, for example, with some drawImage calls of images that overlap the damaged regions but should not paint outside of the clipping area. clearing (and also not repainting) is not possible since IE10 does not clip the area as the other browsers do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in IE10. I posted a similar issue here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/782736/canvas-clearrect-fails-with-non-rectangular-yet-simple-clipping-paths

MS says, "Yeah its a bug. Wait several years for us to fix it." Too bad for MS all the other browsers work now.